# Unable to inject class with DI

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, aurelia, aurelia-dialog

I have a class that uses an instance of `DialogService` from 'aurelia-dialog` to open almost every dialog in my Aurelia application. In a very abstract way the class looks like this:

```
export class DialogTrigger{
    triggerDialogA() {...}
    triggerDialogB() {...}
    triggerDialogC() {...}
}
```

Everything works fine until I try to inject `DialogTrigger` to one of the dialogs.

So let's say that I want to create a new dialog, DialogD. I simply add another method `triggerDialogD()` in `DialogTrigger` that opens a new dialog with a `DialodD` view model and everything works. But if I want my new dialog to also trigger one of the other dialogs (A,B or C) by using an instance of `DialogTrigger` everything falls apart.

If I inject `DialogTrigger` into `DialogD` I always get an error:

> key/value cannot be null or undefined. Are you trying to inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?

If I remove the dependency, the dialog works.

**TL;DR**
I have a `DialogTrigger` class that opens `aurelia-dialog`s. DI fails when I inject `DialogTrigger` to any dialog instantiated by it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a circular dependency issue.

You would have to use path strings to reference the dialogs inside `DialogTrigger`. You cannot import the `Dialog` into `DialogTrigger` and then also import `DialogTrigger` into the `Dialog`.

---

This would work:

```
import { DialogService } from 'aurelia-dialog';

export class DialogTrigger {
  static inject = [DialogService];

  constructor(dialogService) {
    this._dialogService = dialogService;
  }

  openDialogA() { this._dialogService.open({ viewModel: './prompt' }); }
  openDialogB() { this._dialogService.open({ viewModel: './prompt' }); }
}
```

---

This **WILL NOT** work:

```
import { DialogService } from 'aurelia-dialog';
import { Prompt } from './prompt';

export class DialogTrigger {
  static inject = [DialogService];

  constructor(dialogService) {
    this._dialogService = dialogService;
  }

  openDialogA() { this._dialogService.open({ viewModel: Prompt }); }
  openDialogB() { this._dialogService.open({ viewModel: Prompt }); }
}
```

---

Another option is to pass the reference to `DialogTrigger` in the `open()` function's `model: {}` parameter. Like so:

```
this._dialogService.open({ viewModel: './prompt', model: { dialogTrigger: this }  });
```